# Download a csv file containing the contents of a table

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have 100 tables on my page and I would like a button that downloads the contents of each table to a csv file if the check box in the table is checked. Here is the code for the tables.

```
for(int i = 0; i <100; i++){%>
<table style="text-align: left;" id="Table<%= i %>" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" frame="box">
  <input type="checkbox" name='checkbox<%= i %>' checked> Include <br>
  <%String[][] p = players1.remove(0);
  for(int j=0;j<9;j++){ %>
    <tr>
    <%for(int k=0;k<10;k++){%>
    <td style="vertical-align: top"><%= p[j][k]%><br></td>
    <%}%>
    </tr>
  <%} %>
```

Edit:
Pic of the tables on the webpage. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF3WA.jpg
I would like the csv to pretty much have the same look. Contents of one table followed by an empty row then contents of the next table and so on.

Comment: hold up - you don't have a <th>, so what do you expect the key to be in the csv file?

Comment: I do not want keys. Just the info in the table. I'll add a pick of these table to help visualize it.

Comment: Are you asking how to build the list of tables with checkboxes, which is what code would indicate, or are you asking how to generate the CSV file for each table, or are you asking how to download multiple CSV files in one response?

Comment: 1 CSV file that includes all tables that have the corresponding checkbox checked

Answer (score 0):

You should create another jsp that generates CSV instead of HTML. And add these two lines into the jsp:

```
response.setContentType("text/csv"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.csv");
```

This would make browser ask user to save the file instead of trying to display it.

Edit: example of outputting CSV from jsp:

```
<%for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
        %>"<%= p[j][k]%>",<%
    }
    // now the new line:
    %>
<%} %>
```

Then, link to that jsp from another page. Something like this:

```
<a href="getcsv.jsp">Download as CSV</a>
```

Comment: The problem with this strategy is that there is other information on the page that I do not want on the csv. Or am I misunderstanding this and that wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: What I am suggesting is that you create a **separate** jsp and only produce the CSV there, not HTML.

Comment: Any chance there is an example of something like this that I could see?